# SSRS supress MAIN report based on condition, go directly to subreport 1 or 2

Tags: reporting-services, report, subreport

Ok, LOTS of info out there on hiding sub-reports but we need to hide the main report or rather, when the report is ran for SOME customers that have a default "Condition" the report automatically goes directly to the sub report 2.

We have the reports built the same for every customer....this report is designed to be broken down based on division. Some customers do not have division details so we set these tables\columns to a default which allows the main report to function by drilling down. For these customers though that do not use division data, the main (and in this case 1st sub-report) are basically worthless. We would like to set a condition that when the report is RAN by the customer, the MAIN and 1st sub-report are skipped based on default values for the division information. It really doesnt matter that there are 2 sub-reports I guess, we just need to know how to ignore the primary report if this is possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would move all the "MAIN" report content to a new subreport, and convert the "MAIN" report to be an empty shell, containing only subreports.

Comment: Thanks, due to lack of responses and information online it would appear there may not be an option to hide the main report as we were looking to do. I'll look into doing this.